# Can we sum accelerations to get a total acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, vectors

I was looking at this question (from the picture below) the other day and I did it by adding the forces in the $x$ direction using Newton's second law and I got the right answer.

My friend on the other hand did it simply and much quicker: He told me that the we can just find the resultant acceleration of the mass suspended by making a right triangle, with one of the legs being gravity and the other being the acceleration of the truck. He then simply saw that $\frac{a}{g}=\tan(\theta)$, therefore $a = gtan(\theta)$.

I thought there was something wrong with this thinking or that it wasn't proper and that my friend was just lucky. Is there anything wrong with this way of thinking?

[image: This is the question]

Comment: Acceleration is a vector quantity, and the rules of vector addition is generally the same rules as geometry of triangles, so yes, you add three vectors by doing the "tip-to-tail" method and obtain a triangle. You then continue by obtaining the sin/cosine of the angle and such.

Comment: Also, he did a Newtonian addition of forces without knowing it. A correct way of doing this is that in the upwards direction, the sum of forces is $0=Tcos\theta-mg$ and in the sideways direction $ma=Tsin\theta$, where $m$ is the mass of the ball and $T$ is the tension on the string. Now we can obtain "$a$" by substitution (or just do $\frac{Tsin\theta}{Tcos\theta}=\frac{ma}{mg}$. The mass and the tension cancels and you'd end up thinking you only did accelerations.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! Can you put your answer as a response so I can vote it

Comment: Don't really care about the upvotes, but alright :)

Comment: Acceleration is  a FOUR-vector quantity whose magnitude should be zero (in order to conserve the four-velocity, another four vector quantity). Wikipedia has a good intro to both of these concepts.

Comment: @R.Rankin, the tag is Newtonian mechanics. Introducing 4-vectors to this types of questions will make it more difficult. In doing so I might as well introduce curved spaces.

Comment: @Gradient137  apologies, I missed the tag. The question smacked me across the face as being like those that led Einstein to special relativity. Turning a 3-vector to a 4 is not so crazy as turning flat space to full differential geometry lol!

Comment: @R.Rankin, ikr, the picture with the train gives that impression, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly true that accelerations can be added using the ideas of vector addition but this is an example of the correct answer being found with incorrect reasoning.

The mass $m$ has two forces acting on it, the tension in the string $\vec T$ and the attractive gravitational force on the mass due to the Earth $m\vec g$ where $\vec g$ is the gravitational field strength not an acceleration - there is no downward acceleration of the mass.

[image]

The free body diagram is shown on the left and the addition of forces diagram to five the net force $\vec F _{\rm net} = \vec T + m \vec g$ is shown in the middle.

Using Newton's second law $\vec F_{\rm net} = m \vec a$

So the problem now boils down to using the right hand diagram to get the necessary relationship.
It is the right hand diagram which shows why just considering accelerations seems to work as both $mg$ and $ma$ have a common factor $m$ which cancels out when finding the tangent of the angle $\theta$ and $g$ is incorrectly thought of as the acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! I was wondering how he could just vector add g and a, I forgot g is not an acceleration and the mass is not even accelerating downwards!

Comment: isn't g an acceleration cause it has units of m/s^2. And I don' get how the acceleration of the mass is the same as the acceleration of the truck (It's not part of the original question but plz help). Also, when I think about it, the mass is accelerating downwards right? It's going to swing back down because it accelerated due to gravity.

Comment: @Plzhelp In this question the mass is only accelerating horizontally with an acceleration $a$. The weight of the mass $mg$ is balanced by the upward component of the tension in the string so there is no vertical acceleration.

Comment: OMG! I GET IT, SO as the truck is accelerating its just stuck hanging there its not swinging back down!

Comment: @Plzhelp The problem is that the symbol $g$ is used to represent two quantities the acceleration of free fall and the gravitational field strength. I prefer to give the acceleration the unit $\rm m\, s^{-2}$ and the field strength the unit $\rm N\, kg^{-1}$ to differentiate between them although both forms are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks so much, but one more question. As the mass is hanging, what keeps it from swinging back down? Is there another force? I mean its not going up or down so the two forces cancel out. But whats stopping the mass from swinging back down.

Comment: @What you have to realise is that the mass is accelerating horizontally and the horizontal component of the tension provides the force to produce this acceleration. As the mass tries to swing back the support at the top of the string accelerates at the same rate is the mass and so relative to the support the mass does not move.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks so much, cleared all my doubts. :) I wish I could upvote twice

Answer (score 2):

As I stated from the comments,

Acceleration is a vector quantity, therefore you can add it vectorially by the "tip-to-tail" method. Given so, you will arrive with triangles for which you can calculate the quantities of the vectors by geometry/trigonometry.

When doing the Newtonian addition of forces, the mass and tension from the string cancels, leaving you with equations in terms of the accelerations and angles. Therefore, your friend did use Newtonian force additions without knowing it.